# What is the most efficient way to declare functions in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function

I have always learned that to declare a function in javascript you should do something like:

```
function myfunction(fruit){
    alert('I like ' + fruit + '!');
}
```

or something like:

```
var myfunction = function(fruit){
    alert('I like ' + fruit + '!');
};
```

However, most recently, I have noticed that some people actually define functions as constants:

```
const myfunction = fruit=> alert('I like ' + fruit + '!');
```

Or even using the keyword `let`:

```
let myfunction = fruit=> alert('I like ' + fruit + '!');
```

At this point I am quite confused.

- Why so many ways of defining functions?
- When/where should I use each one?
- Which way is more efficient?

Comment: About efficiency, I do not think this could ever be a bottleneck

Comment: Then why so many ways? There has to be an advantage to doing it differently right? It is not like developers just create do things for the heck of it :D

Comment: I was wondering which is the recommended style declaring functions now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it will depend on your needs. For example

this will define your function with `myfunction` name on your local scope

```
function myfunction(fruit){
    alert('I like ' + fruit + '!');
}
```

on the other hand, the code below will define a **variable** called `myfunction` that points to an annonimous function inside your local scope.

```
var myfunction = function(fruit){
    alert('I like ' + fruit + '!');
};
```

while the code below will define an [arrow function of ECMA6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) that are not supported by all browsers at the current date. Besides, `let` statement declares a block scope local variable, optionally initializing it to a value. So your `myfunction` variable won't be seen after the code block is closed.

```
let myfunction = fruit=> alert('I like ' + fruit + '!');
```

`let` allows you to declare variables that are limited in scope to the block, statement, or expression on which it is used. You can read more and see some [examples here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)

As the oficial documentation says:

> The const declaration creates a read-only reference to a value. It
>   does not mean the value it holds is immutable, just that the variable
>   identifier cannot be reassigned.

```
const myfunction = fruit=> alert('I like ' + fruit + '!');
```

So if you try to reassign `myfunction` it will fail (silently) (but does not fail in Safari)

```
// this will fail silently in Firefox and Chrome 
myfunction = fruit=> alert('No! I DO NOT like ' + fruit + '!');
```

About `let` and `const` similarities the MDN reference says that

> Constants are block-scoped, much like variables defined using the let
>   statement. The value of a constant cannot change through
>   re-assignment, and it can't be redeclared.

So, as [Aurelio de Rosa says](http://www.sitepoint.com/preparing-ecmascript-6-let-const/),

> constants share a feature with variables declared using let in that
>   they are block-scoped instead of function-scoped

Read more about `const` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)

Comment: what about `const`? Is there any difference between `const` and `let`?

Comment: I'll write it in a moment =)

Comment: "*it will fail silently*" - it should not. Try using strict mode. In sloppy mode, browsers have implemented all kind of legacy compatibilities, including assignability.

Answer (score 1):

Using `const` makes it so that function variable (or constant in this case) can't be re-assigned to something else. So the function can't be modified.

Using `let` restricts the scope of the function to the block it was defined in, versus `var` which restricts the scope of the function to the execution context. As defined on MDN:

> The scope of a variable declared with var is its current execution context, which is either the enclosing function or, for variables declared outside any function, global.

For example, using `let` inside a for loop would restrict that variable to the for loop.

As for efficiency, I don't see how any of these could impact performance, but there could be nuances that I am unaware of. I doubt anyone would ever see any noticeable difference in performance.

Answer (score 1):

> const

- provides a read only reference to your function variable, you can see it as a constant function, but don't think of it as an immutable one.

> let

- allows you to create a local function, meaning that it's scope will be valid only within the enclosing block where it resides.

MDN references:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const

**Note**: if I remember correctly, let and const are not interpreted correctly by all browsers.